# php- Returning all times between 2 times

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a reservation system for iPads, I have a form that posts a start time and an end time to the processing page which then calls a function, it was working well until I added 15 min increments. Here is the form:

```
<select name='hr_start'>
<option value=""></option>
<option value="08">8AM</option>
<option value="09">9AM</option>
<option value="10">10AM</option>
<option value="11">11AM</option>
<option value="12">12PM</option>
<option value="13">1PM</option>
<option value="14">2PM</option>
<option value="15">3PM</option>
</select>
:<select name='min_start'>
<option value=""></option>
<option value="0">00</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
<option value="45">45</option>

</select>
to
<select name='hr_end'>
<option value=""></option>
<option value="09">9AM</option>
<option value="10">10AM</option>
<option value="11">11AM</option>
<option value="12">12PM</option>
<option value="13">1PM</option>
<option value="14">2PM</option>
<option value="15">3PM</option>
</select>
:<select name='min_end'>
<option value=""></option>
<option value="0">00</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
<option value="45">45</option>
</select>
<input type='hidden' name='day' value='<? echo $day ?>' hidden />
<input type='hidden' name='month' value='<? echo $month ?>' hidden />
<input type='hidden' name='year' value='<? echo $year ?>' hidden />
<input type='hidden' name='type' value='<? echo $type?>' hidden />
<input type="submit" value="Reserve Assets" />
</form>
```

and this is the code that puts the above values in arrays:

```
$hour_start = $_POST['hr_start'];
$min_start = $_POST['min_start'];

$hour_end = $_POST['hr_end'];
$min_end = $_POST['min_end'];

$h = array();
$m = array();


for($i=$hour_start; $i<=$hour_end; $i++) {
  $h[] = $i;
}
//array_unshift($h, $hour_start);
//array_push($h, $hour_end);
for($i=$min_start; $i<=$min_end; $i++) {
$m[] = $i;
}
array_unshift($m, $min_start);
array_push($m, $min_end);
array_push($m, $min_end);
$requested = $_POST['requested'];
```

below is the function that creates the reservation records, `$m` is the month, `$d` is the day, `$y` is the year, `$h` is the array of hours (24 hour format: 15 14 12 etc) and `$m` is the array of minutes (0,15,30,45), `$at` is the type of asset (a 5 digit id) :

```
function generate_confimation ($m, $d, $y, $h, $m1, $at, $numrequested, $user) {
echo '<pre>';

var_dump($h);
var_dump($m1);
echo '</pre>';
foreach ($h as $index => $value)
{
 $t1 =  $h[$index];
 $t2 = $m1[$index];

//$time = $t;
//echo $time;
//echo $utime;
$numbers = array_map('_getNumber', $h);

$startTime = min($numbers);
$endTime = max($numbers);
//$endTime = $endTime;



$startTime = mktime($startTime, 0, 0, $m, $d, $y);
$endTime = mktime($endTime, 0, 0, $m, $d, $y);
$num_avaliable = num_available($m, $d, $y, $t1, $t2, $at);
if ($numrequested > $num_avaliable) {
$error = 'ERROR NOT ENOUGH ASSETS TO FURFILL REQUEST';
return $error;
}
}
mysql_query(
"INSERT INTO transactions(user, start, end)
VALUES('$user', '$startTime', '$endTime')");
$txnid = mysql_insert_id();





/*
$check1 = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM assets WHERE type_id = '$at'");

$check12 = mysql_num_rows($check1);
echo $numrequested;
if ($numrequested > $check12) {
echo 'ERROR NOT ENOUGH ASSETS TO FURFILL REQUEST';
return;
}
*/

//$x = 0;
$numrequested = $numrequested +1 ;
$numrequested;
foreach($h as $t){
$x = 0;
$time = $t;
$ftime = "$time:00:00";
//echo $ftime;
$utime = mktime($time, 0, 0, $m, $d, $y);
//echo $utime;

$assetfetch = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM assets WHERE type_id = $at") or die('ERROR: THERE WAS A SERVER ERROR<br>Please click <a href="reserve.php"> here</a> and try again and then Contact Your Network Administrator for Assistance<br><br>
There may be additional errors, but the server did not report them');
$numrequested = $numrequested - 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($assetfetch)) {
        $assetid= $row['id'];
        //echo $assetid;
        //echo '<br>';
        $numquery = mysql_query("SELECT *
            FROM reservations
            WHERE asset_id = $assetid AND
            start = '$utime'") or die('ERROR: THERE WAS A SERVER ERROR<br>Please click <a href="reserve.php"> here</a> and try again and then Contact Your Network Administrator for Assistance<br><br>
There may be additional errors, but the server did not report them');
$numfind = mysql_num_rows($numquery);
if ($numfind == '0')  {
$query = 
"INSERT INTO reservations(asset_id, user, start, txnid)
VALUES('$assetid', '$user', '$utime', '$txnid')";
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$x++;
if ($x >= $numrequested){
break;
}
}
}






}


return $txnid;

}
```

I am not sure where the problem is, but any help is appreciated!

Comment: We can't tell you WHERE the problem is, if you don't tell us WHAT the problem is. You said what broke it but you didn't say how it is broken.

Answer (score 0):

`$m` is not an array of (0,15,30,45) since your increment of `$i` is 1 on:

```
for($i=$min_start; $i<=$min_end; $i++) {
$m[] = $i;
}
```

should be

```
for($i=$min_start; $i<=$min_end; $i+=15) {
$m[] = $i;
}
```

Comment: for each $m there needs to be a $h so with a starting $h of 8 and a $m of 15 and ending $h = 10 and $m = 15 the array needs to look like this: $h = (8,8,8,9,9,9,9,10,10) $m = (15,30,45,0,15,30,45,0,15)

Comment: @RileyChilds that's why the increment of `$i` should be 15 and not 1, so the all the values in `$m` are multiplies of 15